# CSS remove effect for mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, hover, overlay

I have a hover effect over images with some caption on it.

I would like to make this permanent for mobile users, or someone using a touch only device.

is it possible to dynamically change a) with b) dependant on a users screen size?

```
layout-caption-overlay-hover
```

with

```
layout-caption-overlay
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @media css rule

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    /* Style for the mobile */
    .layout-caption-overlay {
        /* style of your layout-caption-overlay-hover style */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I would like to disable hover for small screensizes, rather than style the overlay differently for different screen sizes.

Is this possible in CSS?

Comment: You can't disable the 'hover' event.
But you can apply a different style when hovered for each different screen sizes using the media query.

Comment: Can you make the hover fixed?

Comment: Thanks btw, that definitely gives me the option of disabling it using opacity.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Bastien,

After much research, I didn't quite find the answer I was looking for, but I did find a work around, based in part on your suggestion. I hope that this helps someone at some stage. I'm using squarespace btw.

N.B. 
I'm a total CSS novice, so there could be a much simpler way of achieving this, however this is what worked for me. Alternate suggestions and constructive criticism welcome.

---

Using 
`@media only screen and (min-width: 640px)`
I set two instructions.

a) Turn opacity of hover layer to .85 when screen size is above 640px

b) Hide the text box positioned underneath the image/overlay when screen size goes below 640px. I've copied and pasted the text appearing on the overlay into this.

```
@media screen and (min-width:640px) /* do the action below until screen with goes below 640px */

{.sqs-block-image .image-block-outer-wrapper.layout-caption-overlay .intrinsic .image-caption-wrapper,
.sqs-block-image .image-block-outer-wrapper.layout-caption-overlay-hover .intrinsic .image-caption-wrapper 
{opacity: .85!important;}  /* Make overlay opacity 0.85 */
#block-yui_3_17_2_2_1447934533987_10333  /* Target this specific block*/
        {display:none;}  /* Keep this block hidden until screen goes below 640px */
```

The above code targets screens above 640px for everything else I needed to set the opacity to 0. This also sets the background color of the overlay:

```
#innovation2015 /* Targeting the specific section/page in my homepage */

{
.sqs-block-image .image-block-outer-wrapper.layout-caption-overlay .intrinsic .image-caption-wrapper,
.sqs-block-image .image-block-outer-wrapper.layout-caption-overlay-hover .intrinsic .image-caption-wrapper 
{background-color: rgb(10,148,214); /* Sets background colour of overlay */
 opacity: 0;}
}
```

---

Lastly, you can use this amazing Chrome addon to identify individual Squarespace block numbers:

**Squarespace Collection/Block Identifier**: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/squarespace-collectionblo/bggpdfnccodbnmcndckmeehdjkjojkde